# Show federated connections stored in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, federated-table

I am feeling little bit stupid about this topic so I have to ask.

I am using `Federated` engine to be able to retrieve data from another database via [CREATE SERVER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create-server.html) instead of using [CONNECTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create-connection.html)

Works like a charm but... how can I retrieve the servers I created?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can look in table **servers** at schema **mysql** like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.servers;
```

Comment: whoa. As I expected, just a simple query. Thanks!

Comment: With this you can see a stored login and password for FEDERATED connection.